# How to create custom coding rules in xcode for objective C and swift?

Tags: xcode, coding-style

How to create custom coding rules in xcode for objective C and swift ?
like code should maintain expected coding standards if it doesn't match coding standard then it should throw error or warnings ?

Comment: You should take a look at [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) and its possibility to add [custom rules](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#defining-custom-rules).

Comment: thanks, what about objective C ?